# Is there any way to detect the event on input field, when it's disabled using angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, events, detect

I am trying to fetch any event event input field is disabled.

```
<input [disabled]='disableTextbox' (click)="delectInput()">
```

This above is my input field. I am trying to fetch the event when it's going in disabled state.
Here is my [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-input-disable-3gq3sc?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts).
Anyone know if Is there any way to do detect any event blur click hover when input is disabled?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no event, when the field becomes disabled. There is no way to detect any event, when the input is disabled. But the way you have it set up in your example, you could detect those events for the `div`, which is surrounding the input.

Comment: Why are you using Angular 4? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Thank you for your replay. Sorry, here Angular 4 just used this for example Currently, I am using Angular 16.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the same example code but change the function in the HTML by changing it into `<div (click)="toggleDisable($event)">`. Then you can add onto the toggleDisable function to `event.target.style.cursor = 'none';`.